# JSF+Primefaces Form issue (Not Working)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

All, deploying my new application in production I started to have a new problem and I hope you can help me out
This application is using JSF2 and PRIMEFACES.

The login xhtml code is below:

```
<h:form>
    <p:messages id="messages_login" showDetail="false" closable="true" showIcon="true"/>
    <p:inputText value="#{loginMB.email}" label="#{bundle.label_email}" placeholder="#{bundle.label_email}" styleClass="Container80 Fnone MarAuto Fs18" required="true"  validatorMessage="#{bundle.emailInvalido}">
        <f:validateRegex pattern="^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$" for="email"  />
    </p:inputText>

    <div class="EmptyBox10"></div> 

    <p:password value="#{loginMB.password}" id="senha" label="#{bundle.label_password}" placeholder="#{bundle.label_password}" required="true"  feedback="false" styleClass="Container80 Fnone MarAuto Fs18" /><br/>
    <p:commandLink action="#{loginMB.showForgotPasswordPanel}" value="#{bundle.link_forgot_password}"  ajax="true" update="loginPanel" immediate="true"/>

    <div class="EmptyBox10"></div> 

    <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{loginMB.rememberSession}" /> <h:outputText value="#{bundle.label_keep_signin}"  escape="false"/>

    <div class="EmptyBox20"></div> 

    <p:commandButton action="#{loginMB.login}" value="#{bundle.btn_login}" ajax="true" update="messages_login" styleClass="Wid80 ui-corner-all"/>
</h:form>
```

It works fine in test and dev environments which the URL is not root (eg. http://localhost:8080/AppName/landing.jsf) but it doesn't work in production that the URL is http://www.example.com/

Looking at the rendered HTML the form looks like this
TEST (working)

```
<form id="j_idt11" name="j_idt11" method="post" action="/AppName//landing.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
...
</form>
```

but in production it looks like this (NOT WORKING)

```
<form id="j_idt11" name="j_idt11" method="post" action="//landing.jsf" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
...
</form>
```

The browser returns the following error:

```
jquery.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=6.1:25 
OPTIONS http://landing.jsf/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I appreciate your inputs to have this fixed...

Comment: Could you paste the code from the #{loginMB.login}? Or at least the logic for generating the action string?

Comment: Also, which PF version are you using? I checked some code and both dev and prod have /AppName in the form action attribute...

Comment: Sure you are not using a reverse proxy or something like this in one of the environments? And where do the double slashes come from. Uncommon for me

Comment: It is not even calling loginMB.login so i dont think the problem is there

Comment: The version is **Primefaces 6.1**

Comment: No reverse proxy.. i just tested in dev environment, if i put it as root i have the same issue

Comment: OK.. i found the issue.
The problem was with the filter that checks if the user is logged in or not, and it was not forwarding correct to the landing page.Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. i found the issue. 
The problem was with the filter that checks if the user is logged in or not, and it was not forwarding correct to the page that contains the login form.
Thanks for your comments it help me to realize that something weird was in the code